# How to show links on the map based on link ID?

Tags: here-api

I have created a custom routing algorithm that uses traffic data to energy optimal route between two points, and I would like to show the route on the map. I have the sequence of links on the optimal paths with their associated link IDs. Right now I am using GeoJSON LineString format to show the links on the map. I am wondering if there is a way to find the link's geometry by its link ID and add it as a layer to the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Fleet Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets API to retrieve Map Data such as Link Attributes including geometry with Link ID.

Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/pde.html

To get link's geometry by its Link ID please use LINK_FC1...5 or ROAD_GEOM_FC1...5 Road link info, geometry for map display layers.

Please see this https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/request-constructing.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful, however I am looking to find a way to highlight a sequence of links on the map (i.e. like what routing api can give us). Is there a way to highlight links by their IDs on the map?

Comment: Does it mean how to draw poly lines by link ids on HERE map?

Comment: Correct! That is exactly what I want.

Comment: Is there a way to draw poly lines by link ids? (instead of lat long positions?)